# checking Marklogic connection by shell script

Tags: shell, marklogic

I need a shell script that checks  Marklogic connection status.I would pass the connection uri to script and the script would check if the connection is working. What's a way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In V7  xcc and app server URL's are incompatible.
XCC uses `xcc://user:name@host:port`
App servers use `http://host:port`

the xcc scheme wont be recognized by a pure HTTP client nor will it be recognized by marklogic's app server.

So first - you need to define what "running" means to you.
In V7 there is a new 'HealthCheck" app which is primarily for use on AWS but has the side effect of being a builtin application on MarkLogic which can be accessed via HTTP with a get and returns "200 OK" if the marklogic server is both running and "healthy" ... You can change how it determines that, out of the box the definition of "healthy" is that the server is fully installed and has access to the security database.

The HealthCheck app runs on port 7997 ... so any program that can do a get to

```
http://server:7997
```

Can check if it returns "200 OK' or not

But to refine the answer, what do you mean by "connection" ... the standard definition of "connection" cannot be sent to an unrelated program by a URL as a "connection" is a currently active HTTP (TCP/IP) connection - that doesn't map to a URL ... its a property of the currently running program.

but if you mean "Is the server active" the above suggestion should work.
If you mean "Is this particular marklogic app up and running" then you need to create a "status" or "healthcheck" or reuse one, but it shouldn't have side effects.  You don't want your connection check to reuse say the "delete all documents" endpoint.

Comment: The xcc: connect string is something specific to the XCC library. Under the covers an XDBC app server still 'talks' HTTP-like requests. You can telnet to it if you like, and even hit is with a browser. You won't get data out though, unless you understand the XDBC-flavor HTTP calls it is expecting..

Comment: Thanks for all the info.

Answer (score 1):

**MarkLogic 6.x or lesser**

Here is the function that I use. If it returns HTTP 20X (200) everything is ok. 
Otherwise server has problems.

```
function PingMarkLogic($server)
{
    $uri = "http://$($server):8001/cluster-status.xqy"
    $adminCredential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "admin", $(ConvertTo-SecureString "admin" -Force -AsPlainText)
    try
    {
        $resp1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method "GET" -Credential $adminCredential -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        return $resp1.StatusCode
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException] 
    {
        return $resp1.StatusCode
    }

}
```

If you want to detect if it is installed but not configured (for example waiting for entering License) add `-MaximumRedirection 0` to Invoke-WebRequest and look for HTTP 302 response as request to `http://server:8001/cluster-status.xqy` would be redirected giving a 302 and the redirection will return HTTP 200

**MarkLogic 7.x or higher**

There is a new default AppServer called HealthCheck in port 7997. It has the advantage that does not require credentials. More info [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2.pdf)

The function then is easier

```
function PingMarkLogic($server)
{
    $uri = "http://$($server):7997"
    try
    {
        $resp1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method "GET" -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        return $resp1.StatusCode
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException] 
    {
        return $resp1.StatusCode
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also use Rest API https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/servers@view=status

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know whether MarkLogic service is running, or whether a particular app server within MarkLogic is running? I guess I would send an HTTP request to one of the MarkLogic ports. If that responds, it is alive..

HTH!

Comment: app server. I would pass an xcc connection uri

Comment: Still the same, it will respond if it is alive even though it will probably won't understand ordinary HTTP calls.

Comment: Small addition: you do need to use the http protocol to use this method. And user:pass@ notation may not be supported by specific HTTP clients. But otherwise it should work..

Comment: Thanks.Http sounds fine by me.